# How do I catch syntax error in unix system commands

Tags: c++

I am using function `popen` for executing the system commands. My code is fine to me when the format of syntax is correct. Suppose I gave a incorrect syntax to the `popen`, I didn't know how to say. ***There is an error in the syntax***. Here I include the sample code and input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

    //correct syntax
    string sysCmd="awk -v FIELDWIDTHS=\"10 8 10 5\" '19970517>=gensub(/(....)(....)/,\"\\\\2\\\\1\",1,$2){print $1}' awktst.txt";

    //Incorrect syntax- extra closing braces found
    //string sysCmd="awk -v FIELDWIDTHS=\"10 8 10 5\" '19970517>=gensub(/(....)(....)/,\"\\\\2\\\\1\",1,$2)){print $1}' awktst.txt";

    FILE *in;
    in=popen(sysCmd.c_str(),"r");
    if(in==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Error in System Cmd Processing "<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

    char *buff=NULL;
    size_t maloc=0;

    while(getline(&buff, &maloc, in) != EOF){
        cout<<buff;
        free(buff);
        buff=NULL;
    }
    pclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Input Sample

```
Bharath   010619925,1,000,00  100
Ragul     10302002  2,000.00  600
Bala      11171993  3,000.00  500
Arjun     05142003  4,000.00  400
Vimal     06301997  5,000.00  100
Ramesh    05171997  1,000.00  300
Kamal     05151997  2,000.56  200
Vinoth    04201997  3,000.00  500
```

How can I catch error exception when I run the code with incorrect syntax?

Comment: It's C++ not C! They're different languages. Please select the correct tag in the future.

Comment: @tambre Probably is C++ without OOP ;)

Comment: What is your example of an incorrect syntax? What happens when you use it?

Comment: In practice, I would either write a separate shell script `mymaketable` and run `in = popen("mymaketable awktst.test", "r")` in the C++ program (and then you can develop and test your `mymaketable` script separately), or avoid using `system` or `popen` on complex commands (and design the program otherwise). Tricky calls to `system` or to `popen` are bad smell (beware of [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)...)

Comment: This is a horrible C/C++ mixture hack, using `stdio.h` instead of `cstdio` and `FILE`, `popen` none of which belongs into C++ program.

Answer (score 3):

You catch it when you call `pclose`.  `awk` is going to write a nice error message to stderr about the syntax error, your first `getline` will fail to get any data, and then `pclose` will  return the exit status of `awk`, which will be non-zero to indicate that an error occurred.